# How to convert ANSI char ID to Unicode char ID by javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, keyboard, ansi

Function `fromCharCode` doesn't work with international ANSI chars. For example, for Russian ANSI (cp-1251) chars with ID from 192 to 223 it returns special characters. How to fix this issue?

I think, it's required to convert ANSI char ID to Unicode char ID and then use `fromCharCode`. But how to convert ANSI char ID to Unicode char ID (depending on the current locale/codepage)?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Are you using 'ANSI' to denote some of the [ISO 8859-_n_](http://czyborra.com/charsets/) codesets?  If not, what do you mean by 'Russian ANSI'?  If you are dealing with characters of a SBCS (single-byte code set) outside the range of ASCII (0-127 decimal), then you must know the code set to be able to interpret values in the range 128-255 accurately as Unicode characters.  That is, 0xC0 (192) has different meanings in 8859-1 and 8859-2 and 8859-3 and ... so to convert 0xC0 or 192 to a Unicode character, you must know which code set you started with.

Comment: I know that the currect codepage should be used to covert. Russian ANSI is CP-1251.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Russian American National Standards Institute".

Comment: tripleee, but how write correctly, cp-1251?

Comment: @tripleee, blame MS for calling DOS/Windows mode CPs OEM and ANSI.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Yes, Windows Code Page 1251 is correct and understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you know code page that your data is encoded in, just set up a mapping Object with keys being codes in your code page and values being proper Unicode symbols or numeric codepoints and use it to convert your data.

```
mapFromCP1251 = {
   192: 'А',
   193: 'Б',
   194: 'В',
   197: 'Е',
   200: 'И',
   204: 'М',
   207: 'П',
   208: 'Р',
   210: 'Т'
   // etc, I don't feel like typing entire http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP1251 here
}

var string = mapFromCP1251[192] + mapFromCP1251[192] + mapFromCP1251[192] + mapFromCP1251[193] + mapFromCP1251[193] + mapFromCP1251[194]
alert(string) // АААББВ
alert(mapFromCP1251[207]+mapFromCP1251[208]+mapFromCP1251[200]+mapFromCP1251[194]+mapFromCP1251[197]+mapFromCP1251[210]+", "+mapFromCP1251[204]+mapFromCP1251[200]+mapFromCP1251[208]+"!") // Hello, world!
```

Comment: @Altaveron, it's kinda straightforward. Here's example to give you a start.

Comment: Thanks. But I need universal international converting depending locale/codepage.

Comment: @Altaveron, unsurprisingly, that'd mean you'll have to build entire repertoire of conversions from all possible "ANSI" CPs. It isn't that hard, actually, since most of this data is available online in formats easy enough to parse. However this also could mean that you're fighting wrong battle. Modern programs most often should operate in Unicode. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only library I've found that solve this problem:
https://github.com/Niggler/js-codepage

But it takes 1.5 MiB.
Probably, if you only need a few charsets, it would take much less.